# understanding uv maps, materials and textures

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I have made a very basic room. I am trying to make game assets for using in Unity.

In the past Ive made some uv maps but I remember struggling, and this is actually more of a complex shape that I had before.

For now I just want to assign a texture to the wall (I'm happy assigning the texture in Unity if thats easier, I dont need to render anything in Blender)

I've drawn a 'Seam' around one wall. Also, earlier than that I have selected every face on the wall and assigned a second material to it.

(Note: I already imported it to Unity and the two materials appear there, but when I assign a texture as the material it just comes out as a solid colour.)

Is it correct that I can mark a square seam as pictured, and then assign a texture to it? And if so how do I do this, is there any simple tutorials just showing this? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a texture to the material in the texture tab next to materials. Then select the mesh you want textured and bring up UV/Image Editor. To select the texture in UV/Image Editor you have to click the little picture button to bring up the drop down menu and then select the texture from there, while in edit mode, while the mesh you want textured is selected (not the object).

It's a little weird at first.

Comment: I think this answer could do with some images to show the process you're describing.

Comment: thanks guys. I think i follow the instructions but I am currently working on something else, so cannot try this yet. As I say I, I have managed this in the past after some trouble, but have forgotten some of the steps. I think you have explained well enough for me to do it now. And if poss, I'll take some snapshots to show others how its done and post here later